# Pickle не сохраняет словари

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

У меня есть небольшая задачка: нужно записать в файл словарь с помощью модуля pickle. Короче комментариями я все объясню, код:

```
import pickle
dict = {"Егор" : 89} #имеются 
dict2 = {"Коля" : 65} #два словаря

#открываю и записываю первый словарь в файл
with open('pb.data', 'ab') as f: #заранее создал 'pb.data'
    pickle.dump(dict, f)
    f.close()
#хочу совместить два словаря dict и dict2 и поместить это в файл 'pb.data'
with open('pb.data', 'ab') as f: 
    pickle.dump(dict2, f)
    f.close()
#вывожу на экран содержимое файла 
with open('pb.data', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
    print(obj)
    f.close()
```

При запуске программы, выводится на экран только первый словарь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё верно, два словаря записали, два и считывайте:

```py
with open('pb.data', 'rb') as f:
    obj1 = pickle.load(f)
    print(obj1)
    obj2 = pickle.load(f)
    print(obj2)
```

Получаем:

```py
{'Егор': 89}
{'Коля': 65}
```

Просто так объединить словари не получится, Pickle сохраняет их в собственном бинарном формате, где каждый объект имеет начало и конец.

<sub>Кстати, `f.close()` в данном случае использовать не нужно, конструкция `with` закрывает файл автоматически.</sub>

---

Чтобы объединить словари, можно использовать такую функцию:

```py
def append_dict_file(filename, news):
    # Считывание файла
    with open('pb.data', 'rb') as f:
        old = pickle.load(f)
    # Объединение словарей
    old.update(news)
    # Полная перезапись файла
    with open('pb.data', 'wb') as f: 
        pickle.dump(old, f)
```

И использовать так:

```py
dict1 = {"Егор" : 89}
dict2 = {"Коля" : 65}
dict3 = {"Айван" : 77}

with open('pb.data', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dict1, f)

append_dict_file('pb.data', dict2)
append_dict_file('pb.data', dict3)

with open('pb.data', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
    print(obj)
```

Вывод:

```py
{'Егор': 89, 'Коля': 65, 'Айван': 77}
```

<sub>Ещё один момент: в исходном коде было присвоение `dict = ...`, что очень плохо, т.к `dict` – это встроенное наименование, и переписывать их опасно.</sub>

Comment: Спасибо большое, так быстро ответили. Учту все замечания, тем более только учусь.

Comment: @Егор пожалуйста! А благодарность на этом сайте выражают стрелкой вверх и галочкой принятого ответа `:)`

Comment: Ваш ответ принимаю :)